# Is there a way to use asPath in Nextjs13?

Tags: next.js13

In my previous Next project I used asPath from the useRouter hook. Now in Nextjs13 that does not seem to be working anymore. I am aware that there is a hook named usePathname, but that gives the whole url including the language part. Is there a way to get the path without the language part in Nextjs13?

Ofcourse I could just remove the first 3 chars to remove the language part, but I'm looking for a more clean way.

Comment: you can use useSelectedLayoutSegment to get Segment

Comment: Thanks, but that gives the one segment, right? I need the complete path without the locale.

Comment: so use "useSelectedLayoutSegments", this returns all path as an array.

Comment: Thanks, however, this returns a list with segments. To get the path, I would have to convert this to a string with slashes in between the paths. Of course that is possible but it's a lot of work to just get the path. In the previous NextJS version there was a possibility to just get the path. I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
  const pathname = usePathname();
```

from next/navigation

Comment: Do you want an answer to that question? Then please delete it. Do you mean to answer according to [answer]? Then please [edit] to make that more obvious.